# Why isn't my active class on the link getting applied?

Tags: html, css

I want to display a navigation bar and highlight the active page by using the active class.

```
  <body>  <header class="header">
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </body>
```

With this style, I'm able to see the change in color when the link is hovered on, but not when it's active.

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Lato, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
     }
 li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    margin: 14px 16px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.235px;
    /* margin-right: 12px; */
}

li a:hover {
    color: #EE6C4D;
    /* font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0; */
}

li a:active{
    color: #EE6C4D;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `a.active` instead of `a:active`,because `active` is a class not an atribute in your code.

Also,in order to get the expected result,you had better to use different color for test.

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Lato, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
     }
 li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    margin: 14px 16px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.235px;
    /* margin-right: 12px; */
}

li a:hover {
    color: #EE6C4D !important;
    /* font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0; */
}

li a.active{
   color: #0088CC;
}
```

```html
<body>  <header class="header">
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! If I don't use it as a class, should a:active work? I tried that earlier, but it didn't.

Comment: @Nikhat you need to use `a[active='test']`,futher check at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

because you do not really have a class in your css called `.active`

`a:active` is NOT the same as class: `active`

add to your CSS:

```css
.active{
    color: #EE6C4D;
}
```